# Why does the color not change when I press the space bar after copying the hex value?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Once I click generate new color, a new color is generated. Once clicked, I can also press the space bar to generate new colors. But once I click 'Copy hex value', the space bar no longer functions the way is it supposed to. Is there any way to fix this? I assume I need to move the keypress somewhere else?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>
    Color Generator 
</title>
<style>
body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        background: #161818;
        font-family: "Consolas";
    }
    .color {
        margin-top: 300px;
        text-align: center;
    }
    #hex {
        display: block;
        color: white;
        font-size: 100px;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        margin: 0px;
    }
    .color button {
        background: none;
        outline: 10px;
        color: white;
        cursor: pointer;
        font-size: 20px;
        border: 3px solid white;
    }

    .notification {
        position: absolute;
        left: 50%;
        top: 0;
        transform: translate(-50%, -100%);
        transition: transform 0.6s ease;
        border: 2px solid white;
        padding: 12px 30px;
        color: white;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>

 <div class="color">
            <span id="hex">#??????</span>
            <button onclick="genNewColor()">Generate new random color</button>
            <button onclick="copyHexValue()">Copy hex value</button>
        </div>

        <div class='notification'>

        </div>


<script type="text/javascript">
    function genNewColor() {
        var symbols, color;
        symbols = "0123456789ABCDEF";

        color = "#";
        for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            color = color + symbols[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
        }
        document.body.style.background = color;
        document.getElementById("hex").innerHTML = color;
    }

    function copyHexValue() {
        var copyHex = document.createElement("input");
        copyHex.value = document.getElementById("hex").innerHTML;
        document.body.appendChild(copyHex);
        copyHex.select();
        document.execCommand("copy");
        // alert("Copied the hex value " + copyHex.value);
        showNotification(copyHex.value);

        console.log("Copied the hex value " + copyHex.value);
        document.body.removeChild(copyHex);
    }

    document.body.onkeyup = function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 32) {
        }
    };

    const notification = document.querySelector(".notification");

    function showNotification(color) {
        let notificationText;
      // If no color has been picked 
        if (color === "#??????") notificationText = "Generate a color first";
      // Show Color Picked Message
        else notificationText = `Copied hex value ${color}`;
      //Slide down the notification
        notification.style.transform = "translate(-50%,100%)";
      // Add message to notification
        notification.textContent = notificationText;

    //Make Notification slide back up after 2s
        setTimeout(function hideNotification() {
            notification.style.transform = "translate(-50%,-100%)";
        }, 2000);
    }


    
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey when you click `Generate new Random color` your focus drops on this button and that is why by clicking the space bar you just clicking the focused button, when you click on the other button the focus changes.

You can fix it but adding the function call to your space press event

```js
  document.body.onkeyup = function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 32) {
      genNewColor()
    }
  };
```

let me know if it helps.